# how to get notification_id after send friend request hook in buddypress

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I am using buddypress 2.4.0
I am want to do GCM call after this action

1. send friend request
2. Accept friend request

But I am not getting any appropriate hook for that. The hook I am using done not have the parameter notification_id. Please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this hook:

```
do_action_ref_array( 'bp_notification_after_save', array( &$this ) );
```

Found in:

```
buddypress\bp-notifications\classes\class-bp-notifications-notification.php
```

Check the `component_name` in the passed array and if it is something like `friends` - proceed with your task.

Comment: Hye thanks, worked like a charm, thanks for helping me out.

Comment: @SumitDey - you are welcome. Please accept the answer.